# Jhipster Cassandra project not starting

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, jhipster

I have created a new jhipster project with backend as cassandra,
But while starting the application using ./mvnv , i am getting error and application fail to start.

Error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project castrol: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder com.kpit.castrol.service.UserService.passwordEncoder; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.kpit.castrol.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.kpit.castrol.repository.UserRepository com.kpit.castrol.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table user -> [Help 1]

Should i need to create user table in cassandra.

Exception :

2016-07-13 16:03:51.852 ERROR 15114 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.kpit.castrol.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.kpit.castrol.repository.UserRepository com.kpit.castrol.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table user
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5277)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```
enter code here


/**
 * Cassandra repository for the User entity.
 */
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Inject
    private Session session;

    private Mapper<User> mapper;

    private PreparedStatement findAllStmt;

    private PreparedStatement findOneByActivationKeyStmt;

    private PreparedStatement findOneByResetKeyStmt;

    private PreparedStatement insertByActivationKeyStmt;

    private PreparedStatement insertByResetKeyStmt;

    private PreparedStatement deleteByActivationKeyStmt;

    private PreparedStatement deleteByResetKeyStmt;

    private PreparedStatement findOneByLoginStmt;

    private PreparedStatement insertByLoginStmt;

    private PreparedStatement deleteByLoginStmt;

    private PreparedStatement findOneByEmailStmt;

    private PreparedStatement insertByEmailStmt;

    private PreparedStatement deleteByEmailStmt;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        mapper = new MappingManager(session).mapper(User.class);

        findAllStmt = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM user");

        findOneByActivationKeyStmt = session.prepare(
            "SELECT id " +
            "FROM user_by_activation_key " +
            "WHERE activation_key = :activation_key");

        findOneByResetKeyStmt = session.prepare(
            "SELECT id " +
            "FROM user_by_reset_key " +
            "WHERE reset_key = :reset_key");

        insertByActivationKeyStmt = session.prepare(
            "INSERT INTO user_by_activation_key (activation_key, id) " +
            "VALUES (:activation_key, :id)");

        insertByResetKeyStmt = session.prepare(
            "INSERT INTO user_by_reset_key (reset_key, id) " +
            "VALUES (:reset_key, :id)");

        deleteByActivationKeyStmt = session.prepare(
            "DELETE FROM user_by_activation_key " +
            "WHERE activation_key = :activation_key");

        deleteByResetKeyStmt = session.prepare(
            "DELETE FROM user_by_reset_key " +
            "WHERE reset_key = :reset_key");

        findOneByLoginStmt = session.prepare(
            "SELECT id " +
            "FROM user_by_login " +
            "WHERE login = :login");

        insertByLoginStmt = session.prepare(
            "INSERT INTO user_by_login (login, id) " +
                "VALUES (:login, :id)");

        deleteByLoginStmt = session.prepare(
            "DELETE FROM user_by_login " +
                "WHERE login = :login");

        findOneByEmailStmt = session.prepare(
            "SELECT id " +
            "FROM user_by_email " +
            "WHERE email     = :email");

        insertByEmailStmt = session.prepare(
            "INSERT INTO user_by_email (email, id) " +
                "VALUES (:email, :id)");

        deleteByEmailStmt = session.prepare(
            "DELETE FROM user_by_email " +
                "WHERE email = :email");
    }

    public User findOne(String id) {
        return mapper.get(id);
    }

    public Optional<User> findOneById(String id) {
        return Optional.of(findOne(id));
    }

    public Optional<User> findOneByActivationKey(String activationKey) {
        BoundStatement stmt = findOneByActivationKeyStmt.bind();
        stmt.setString("activation_key", activationKey);
        return findOneFromIndex(stmt);
    }

    public Optional<User> findOneByResetKey(String resetKey) {
        BoundStatement stmt = findOneByResetKeyStmt.bind();
        stmt.setString("reset_key", resetKey);
        return findOneFromIndex(stmt);
    }

    public Optional<User> findOneByEmail(String email) {
        BoundStatement stmt = findOneByEmailStmt.bind();
        stmt.setString("email", email);
        return findOneFromIndex(stmt);
    }

    public Optional<User> findOneByLogin(String login) {
        BoundStatement stmt = findOneByLoginStmt.bind();
        stmt.setString("login", login);
        return findOneFromIndex(stmt);
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return mapper.map(session.execute(findAllStmt.bind())).all();
    }

    public User save(User user) {
        User oldUser = mapper.get(user.getId());
        if (oldUser != null) {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(oldUser.getActivationKey()) && !oldUser.getActivationKey().equals(user.getActivationKey())) {
                session.execute(deleteByActivationKeyStmt.bind().setString("activation_key", oldUser.getActivationKey()));
            }
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(oldUser.getResetKey()) && !oldUser.getResetKey().equals(user.getResetKey())) {
                session.execute(deleteByResetKeyStmt.bind().setString("reset_key", oldUser.getResetKey()));
            }
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(oldUser.getLogin()) && !oldUser.getLogin().equals(user.getLogin())) {
                session.execute(deleteByLoginStmt.bind().setString("login", oldUser.getLogin()));
            }
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(oldUser.getEmail()) && !oldUser.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())) {
                session.execute(deleteByEmailStmt.bind().setString("email", oldUser.getEmail()));
            }
        }
        BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
        batch.add(mapper.saveQuery(user));
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getActivationKey())) {
            batch.add(insertByActivationKeyStmt.bind()
                .setString("activation_key", user.getActivationKey())
                .setString("id", user.getId()));
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getResetKey())) {
          batch.add(insertByResetKeyStmt.bind()
              .setString("reset_key", user.getResetKey())
              .setString("id", user.getId()));
        }
        batch.add(insertByLoginStmt.bind()
            .setString("login", user.getLogin())
            .setString("id", user.getId()));
        batch.add(insertByEmailStmt.bind()
            .setString("email", user.getEmail())
            .setString("id", user.getId()));
        session.execute(batch);
        return user;
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
        batch.add(mapper.deleteQuery(user));
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getActivationKey())) {
            batch.add(deleteByActivationKeyStmt.bind().setString("activation_key", user.getActivationKey()));
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getResetKey())) {
            batch.add(deleteByResetKeyStmt.bind().setString("reset_key", user.getResetKey()));
        }
        batch.add(deleteByLoginStmt.bind().setString("login", user.getLogin()));
        batch.add(deleteByEmailStmt.bind().setString("email", user.getEmail()));
        session.execute(batch);
    }

    private Optional<User> findOneFromIndex(BoundStatement stmt) {
        ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);
        if (rs.isExhausted()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(rs.one().getString("id"))
            .map(id -> Optional.ofNullable(mapper.get(id)))
            .get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your exception trace and show your UserService class and the class where you try to autowire it.

Comment: Hi Patrick @Patrick , After creating the project i have not done any changes, it is base application with back end as cassandra , i have created a key space in cassandra and updated it in appication.yml file. Now error is Bean Creation Exception, jhipster is not able to create bean.

Comment: Look at this part of the exception: `Could not autowire method: public void`. maybe there is a typo error. But would be easier to see some code.

Comment: @Patrick i have not touched any code from jhipster, its the blank project with default user management of jhipster

Comment: @Patrick please check the auto generated code,

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [JHipster doc about Cassandra](https://jhipster.github.io/using-cassandra/) you must run the migration tool to create your database.